# Undefined property:stdClass::$skill in C:/XAMPP/htdocs/Saketh/databaseFiles/registrationsubmit.php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

This is my JAVASCRIPT code:

```
angular.module('PopupDemo', ['ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('PopupDemo').controller('PopupDemoCont2', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', '$location', function($scope, $http, $modal, $location) {
  $scope.loading = true;
  var skillvalue = document.getElementById("skill").value;
  $scope.skill = skillvalue;
  var skill1value = document.getElementById("skill1").value;
  $scope.skill1 = skill1value;
  var experiencevalue = document.getElementById("experience").value;
  $scope.experience = experiencevalue;
  var experience1value = document.getElementById("experience1").value;
  $scope.experience1 = experience1value;
  var sailentFeaturevalue = document.getElementById("sailentFeature").value;
  $scope.sailentFeature = sailentFeaturevalue;
  var firstNamevalue = $location.search()['firstName'];
  $scope.firstName = firstNamevalue;
  var middleNamevalue = $location.search()['middleName'];
  $scope.middleName = middleNamevalue;
  var lastNamevalue = $location.search()['lastName'];
  $scope.lastName = lastNamevalue;
  var emailvalue = $location.search()['email'];
  $scope.email = emailvalue;
  var workexperiencevalue = $location.search()['workexperience'];
  $scope.workexperience = workexperiencevalue;

  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Your data will be lost.";
  };

  $scope.url = 'databaseFiles/registrationsubmit.php';

  $scope.regformsubmit = function(isValid) {
    alert("Hello");

    if (isValid) {
      $http.post($scope.url, {
        "firstName": $scope.fname,
        "middleName": $scope.mname,
        "lastName": $scope.lname,
        "email": $scope.email,
        "workexperience": $scope.workexperience
      }).
      success(function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.status = status;
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.result = data;
        alert("Hello");
        alert(data.trim());
        if (data.trim() === 'UPDATED') {
          var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            controller: 'PopupCont',
            templateUrl: 'popup.html',
          });
          //window.location.href = 'userRegistration.html';
        } else {
          $scope.errorMsg = "Login not correct";
          alert("Pease enter the valid crendentials...");
        }
      })
    } else {
      //alert('Please fill up the form completly...');
      //window.location = 'UserRegistration.html';
    }
  }
  //            $scope.open = function () {
  //                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  //                      controller: 'PopupCont',
  //                    templateUrl: 'popup.html',
  //                    
  //                });
  //            }
}]);

angular.module('PopupDemo').controller('PopupCont', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
  $scope.close = function() {
    window.location = 'Login.html';
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
}]);
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @filesource : submit.php
 * @author : Shabeeb  <mail@shabeeb.com>
 * @abstract : simple submission php form
 * @package sample file 
 * @copyright (c) 2014, Shabeeb
 * 
 * 
 *  */
session_start();
require_once 'database_connections.php'; 
$_SESSION['message'] = '';
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database)or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$post_date = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($post_date);

$email= $data->email;
$workexperience = $data->workexperience;
$skill = $data->skill;
$experience = $data->experience;
$skill1 = $data->skill1;
$experience1 = $data->experience1;
$sailentFeature = $data->sailentFeature; 

//echo $firstName;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users set workexperience='$workexperience',skill='$skill',experience='$experience',sailentFeature
='$sailentFeature',skill1='$skill1',experience1='$experience1' where email='$email'");
if ( $result === TRUE ) {
    echo "UPDATED";
} else {
    //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
    echo 'wrong';
}
//if the query is successful, redirect to welcome.php page done!


?>
```

This is the error dialog I'm seeing:

[image: Error Message]

I have two forms to be filled one after the other.So the values I am going to insert into database are not declared in the Java Script.While I did try to initialize the values through IDs, the error is still not fixed!

Can anyone take time to explain how to define the variables in other way?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Just some advice: You've provided extremely limited info regarding your goal and the point at which it fails. That being said, the question is acceptable imo, just provide some more info!

Comment: Improved code formatting. Embedded picture into question itself.

Comment: Update tag 'angular' with 'angularjs'